# java3d detect specific object and not all the collisions

Tags: java, collision

hello everyone i have a 3d game where the player sould not pass through wall. i have problem in detect the collision i have tried the WakeupOnCollisionEntry WakeupOnCollisionExit but there is a problem. imagine a plane and a player on that plane and the plane surrounded with walls and a player should not pass through walls. but when i tried to use the WakeupOnCollisionEntry because the player is on the plane so its detecting it and not working with the walls. my question is if it possible to ignore the plane detection and to specify a specific objects that i want the player to collide with  (like ignore plane and detect the walls). i cant paste here all the code because its alot of code lines so sorry for that i will be very thankful for everyone that can help me with that because im trying to do that about a week and its not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

setCollidable(false); this lina helps avoid collision